# different UIPivkerviews different number of components

Tags: swift, uiview, uipickerview

I'm trying to add different `uipickerviews` to one view, the problem is that that the number of components is set one for all picker views:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

Is it possible to set different number of components for different `uipickerviews`? The same question is for other functions, like number of rows

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int)
```

and source with the components themselves:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int)
```

how can this distinguishing of uipickerviews be implemented in swift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `IBOutlet`s for your pickerViews and then check the pickerview in the function before returning the value

```
@IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var picker2: UIPickerView!

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if pickerView == picker1 {
        return 2
    }
    else {
       return 1
    }
}
```

Edit: If you are creating your pickers programmatically, create properties for them

```
var picker1: UIPickerView?
var picker2: UIPickerView?

func createMyPickers() {
    picker1 = UIPickerView(...
    picker2 = UIPickerView(...
}
```

That way you can access your pickers in the delegate methods!

Comment: thank you! this works, in my case had to use tag to distinguish multiple uipickerviews

Comment: DO NOT RELY ON TAGS!! Make IBOutlets

Comment: I add this picker views programmatically to different subviews , so I can't use IBOutlets(
clicked the green check mark is that marked as answer ?

Comment: Thanks! Also, in that case, just use properties. Will edit the answer. Apple strongly suggests against using tags and so do I since they can get quite tedious to manage